# Get a list of IN persons

Tags: windows, batch-file, duplicates, findstr

I have a file that have many lines and I want to be able, in a batch file, to echo all the lines of the persons that are IN now...

My text file is like this :

```
LEDEE           IN 2016-07-11 07:49:59                                                   
STEPHAN         IN 2016-07-11 07:56:14                                                   
NADIAB          IN 2016-07-11 07:58:30                                                   
ANGEE           IN 2016-07-11 07:58:59                                                   
STEPHAN         OUT 2016-07-11 08:05:25                                                   
STEPHAN         IN 2016-07-11 08:05:29                                                   
ANGEE           OUT 2016-07-11 08:06:05                                                   
ANGEE           IN 2016-07-11 08:06:11                                                   
ANGEE           OUT 2016-07-11 08:16:11                                                   
JOHN            IN 2016-07-11 08:44:42                                                   
PAUL            IN 2016-07-11 08:48:01                                                   
JOHNNY          IN 2016-07-11 08:49:26                                                   
PABLO           IN 2016-07-11 08:49:41
```

I want to be able to echo a list of all the persons that are IN now.
The result should be :

```
LEDEE
STEPHAN
NADIAB
JOHN
PAUL
JOHNNY
PABLO
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Would it ruin the output to pipe it through `sort`?  If not, you could use a `for /F` loop to set a variable to the content of each line; and for each line, if it does not equal the previous line, echo it.  Something like `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('findstr /i "search" "textfile.txt" ^| sort') do ( some stuff )`.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more information.  You'll also need delayed expansion.  See `help setlocal` for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to give you a start:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (text.txt) do set _%%a=%%b
echo ---- current status:
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%x in ('set _ ') do echo %%x
echo ---- People IN:
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_=" %%x in ('set _ ^|find "=IN"') do echo %%x
echo ---- People OUT:
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_=" %%x in ('set _ ^|find "=OUT"') do echo %%x
```

Comment: The person that is OUT should not be in the IN section, even if a precedent line said that he was IN

Comment: this gets the last status for every person. So if one gets OUT and later gets IN again (like Stephan and Angee in your example), shouldn't they be listed as IN?

Comment: ok, they are. (For your example, *all* persons are IN). Add someone to be OUT, and he won't be listed as IN. Edit: with your edited list, ANGEE is listed as OUT and isn't listed as IN.